# How to get all available Chromecast devices?

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I want to add an action for a custom Chromecast button.

I can use a default button ([GCKUICastButton](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender/integrate#top_of_page)) with a default action.

```
let castButton = GCKUICastButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
castButton.tintColor = UIColor.gray
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: castButton)
```

But I need to create my own view with a list of devices that can connect with Chromecast.

How to get all available Chromecast devices?

Answer (score -2):

We highly recommend that you use the widgets in the Cast SDK for both the button and displaying the list of devices. You should use the various styling options to customize the widgets as needed for your branding.